# Можно ли создать новый экземпляр класса по инициативе пользователя, если "да", то как это реализовать? Ну а если "нет", то как надо извернуться?

Tags: c#, классы, логика

Логика программы: Программа работает в цикле - сделано это для того, чтобы рыбы могли "стареть". На каждой итерации цикла пользователь может как вытащить одну из рыбок из аквариума, так и добавить новую рыбку в аквариум(с этим и возникла проблема). Как добавление по моей задумке должно быть реализовано: Пользователь вводит породу рыбы(например, Ancistrus). Создается новая рыба именно этой породы. (здесь и возникает проблема - необходимо ведь создать экземпляр класса (новую рыбу), а для этого надо, значит заранее все это сделать, но это просто кощунство по отношению к ресурсам компьютера. **Так как же сделать так, чтобы именно при команде пользователя создавалась рыба?**)
Первый выделенный фрагмент в коде - функция с помощью которой пользователь смог бы добавить еще одну рыбеху в аквариум(сделано в цикле -> не один раз может повторяться). И тут возникла проблема, над которой я бессилен: пользователь желает добавить рыбу -> необходимо создать еще один экземпляр класса(само-собой с уникальным именем).
На втором фрагменте, выделенным жирным, Вам представлена сама функция "AddFish()", так же она ссылается на функцию аналогичную по названию, но уже из класса Aquarium - эта функция лишь расширяет массив и внедряет туда новую чешуйчатую. **Второй выделенный фрагмент и является проблемой.** (Не представляется возможным создать экземпляр класса с именем введенным пользователем **только что в командную строку**. Меня бы устроило рандомно именовать новые экземпляры класса, однако я не думаю, что это возможно.) Что, собственно говоря, делать, как разрешить данную проблему???
Я придумал лишь одно решение данной проблемы - заранее создать множество экземпляров класса заранее(возможно оставить их со значением "null"), а когда пользователь захочет добавить определенную рыбу в аквариум, то нужная рыба "станет активной", "выйдет из сна", если желаете...

```
'''c#
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int whatToDo;
            string info;
            Random random = new Random();

            Ancistrus ancistrus = new Ancistrus();
            Astronotus astronotus = new Astronotus();
            Barbus barbus = new Barbus();
            Guppy guppy = new Guppy(); //Все вышеперечисленные пользовательские 
//классы наследованы от Fish.

            Fish[] fishes = new Fish[] { ancistrus, astronotus, barbus, guppy };

            Aquarium aquarium = new Aquarium(fishes); //В аквариум добавляются рыбы.


            while (true)
            {   
                Console.WriteLine("Аквариум запущен. Команды для взаимодействия:\n" +
                                  "1 - продолжение жизни;\n" +
                                  "2 - добавить в аквариум рыбу;\n" +
                                  "3 - вытащить из аквариума рыбу;\n");

                info = aquarium.GetInfo(); 
                Console.WriteLine(info); //Выводит информацию о рыбах в аквариуме.

                AgingAll(aquarium._fishes); //Здесь рыбы стареют на 1 год.

                Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadKey().ToString(), out whatToDo);
                switch(whatToDo) //2 - добавить рыбу, 3 - вытащить рыбу,
    // любая другая клавиша - продолжить выполнение программы(рыбы просто постареют).
                {
                    case 2:
                        **AddFish(aquarium);** //добавление рыбы в аквариум. 
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //RemoveFish();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                Console.Clear();
            }
        }

static void AddFish(Aquarium aquarium)
    {
        Console.Write("Рыбу с каким именем вы хотите добавить?  ");
        string nameNewFish = Console.ReadLine();

        if (nameNewFish == Ancistrus.Breed) //Если имя, введенное пользователем аналогично породе Ancistrus, то...
            **Ancistrus nameNewFish = new Ancistrus();** //проблема - как создать новый экземпляр

        aquarium.AddFish(nameNewFish); //уже созданная рыба добавляется в аквариум.
    }
'''
```

Comment: Очень. Очень плохо задан вопрос. Не говоря уже о картинках.

Comment: Подскажите, вы поняли вопрос или нет?

Comment: Ведь я не совсем понимаю, в чем же конкретно он плох)

Comment: Я не понял вопрос.

Comment: Скрины студии? Зачем они тут? У вас проблема с кодом - вот и вставьте код в вопрос. Никто не будет вглядываться в ваши скрины.

Comment: сейчас опишу лучше логику программы

Comment: Моя основная мысль в том, что у вас проблема с кодом, но вместо того, чтобы показать ваш код, вы начинаете что то описывать, какие то скрины вставлять - это все смысла не имеет никакого. Если проблема с кодом - показывайте код.

Comment: показал, только что исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void AddFish(Aquarium aquarium)
{
  Console.Write("Рыбу с каким именем вы хотите добавить?  ");
  string nameNewFish = Console.ReadLine();
  Fish fish = null;

  if (nameNewFish == Ancistrus.Breed)
    fish = new Ancistrus();
  else if (nameNewFish == Astronotus.Breed)
    fish = new Astronotus();

  if (fish != null)
    aquarium.AddFish(fish);
  else 
    Console.Write("Unknown fish - " + nameNewFish);
}
```

Comment: спасибо огромное) Совсем недавно притронулся к ООП. Я и не знал про такой функционал.

Comment: @ВладимирГоворов Пожалуйста. Успехов.